# Binary Search Trees, Breadth First Traversal

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have been sitting on this one for some time. In the Binary Search Tree, when you do a breadth first traversal There is this one line of code that I dont know what it does. In the textbook I am using the code is as follows.

```
public void breadthFirst()
    {
        BSTNode<T> p = root;
        Queue<BSTNode<T>> queue = new Queue<BSTNode<T>>();
        if(p != null)
        {
            queue.enqueue(p); 
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) 
        {
            **p = queue.dequeue();**  
            visit(p); 
            if(p.left != null)
            {
                queue.enqueue(p.left);
            }
            if(p.right != null)
            {
                 queue.enqueue(p.right);
                }
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. The code I am having trouble with is the p = queue.dequeue() which is between the ** **. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Queue contains nodes that we have to visit. Before when we visit a node we take it out of the queue (dequeue) so that it will not be visited again.

Comment: OH okay I got it now. Thank you very much!